# FileNotFound exception when launching an empty WebSphere server

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

There was no project deployed to the Websphere server, and I have yet to enable security feature on the WebSphere Server 7.0.

Could it be from previous attempts to create a server? I've not been successful. The directory `C:\myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\` does not exist because I deleted `tmp1` folder in an attempt to clean my server environment. Repeat deleted and reinstalling the server does not help.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
[11/24/14 11:57:00:930 EST] 0000000e ApplicationMg E   WSVR0100W: An error occurred initializing, MyApplication
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NestedJarException: IWAE0008E An error occurred reading MyApplication.war from C:\myWorkspace
Stack trace of nested exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\MyApplication (The system cannot find the path specified.)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:72)
      at
```

Comment: Try this - start the server, open web console, go to `Enterprise applications`, select `MyApplication`, click Unisnstall and Save. Restart the server.

Comment: i want to try that but i can't even launch the admin console as i get the error "cannot launch the administrative console since the administrative port is not found"

Comment: Where you get that error? In Eclipse? Don't launch console from Eclipse. Start external browser and type http://localhost:9060/ibm/console

Comment: When you start the server, do you have `Open for e-business` in the SystemOut.log? The error you are mentioning shouldn't prohibit server from starting...

Comment: yes i do get the `Open for e-business` in the SystemOut.log but when i run localhost:9060/ibm/console my browser cannot connect to the site

Comment: Look for messsages to check your admin port: `[11/24/14 11:58:52:299 CET] 00000001 TCPChannel    I   TCPC0001I: TCP Channel TCP_1 is listening on host *  (IPv4) port **9061**.
[11/24/14 11:58:52:299 CET] 00000001 WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain WCInboundAdmin.` You can also use `netstat` to see if port is really listening

Comment: you are right managed to find a port **9048** but when i click on `enterprise applications` i get an error 500 `Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.TypeRegistry (initialization failure)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65614/discussion-between-gas-and-bouncinghippo).

Comment: was there ever an answer to this?